# Remap <Space> key doesn't work

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

I was trying to remap some keys to switch to the next buffer, but something doesn't work, I have these lines on my .vimrc file:

```
" Cambia tecla lider a <Space>
let mapleader="<Space>"

" Switch to next buffer
nnoremap <Leader>l :bn<CR>

" Switch to previous buffer
nnoremap <Leader>h :bp<CR>

" Split the window
nnoremap <Leader>k :split<CR>
```

Are those lines okay? or Is there something wrong?

> An observation: when I change `<Leader>` to `<Space>` it works.

Comment: Try `let mapleader = "\<Space>"`. Note the back slash inside the quote.

Answer (score 6):

Inside `:map` commands, the special `:help key-notation` needs to be used, especially for space, because whitespace separates the arguments of `:map`. The `mapleader` is a built-in variable, and as such requires no escaping. You can simply use

```
:let mapleader = ' '
```

Alternatively, if you'd like to stick to the same notation, the keyword needs to be escaped and put in double quotes (cp. `:help expr-quote`):

```
:let mapleader = "\<Space>"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a missing `\`

`let mapleader = "\<Space>"`